# CMUSphinx project works under VC++ but not under GCC

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, codeblocks, cmusphinx

I am trying to build the sphinx tutorial that is provided on the website (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx). The thing is that when I build the tutorial in Visual Studio 2013 it works as expected. When I build it in Code::Blocks with GCC, it compiles, but when I run the executable the console crashes. By opening the debugger it points to an unhandled exception in the file ntdll.dll.

Under build options --> search directories --> Compiler, I have included both the sphinxbase and the pocketsphinx directories.

Under build options --> search directories --> Linker I've included the bin/Release folders of both pocketsphinx and shinxbase

Under build settings --> Linker settings --> Link libraries I've added the sphinxbase.lib and the pocketsphinx.lib from the bin/Release directories of each corresponding project.

Is there any option that I am missing?

The sphinxbase and pocketsphinx libraries were built using VC++.

Comment: This issue is covered in FAQ http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qpocketsphinx_crashes_on_windows_in_lock_file. You need to make sure you are using proper runtime libraries during build.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I was searching for hours